# Error message while initializing Anaconda

Tags: 22.04, anaconda, jupyter, spyder

I'm having the following error message while trying to initialize the Anaconda Application. Would appreciate if you anyone guide me to solve the issues and explain the cause of the error message. Thanks in advance. And appreciate for your time and energy. :)

Ubuntu Version: 22.04

[anaconda_initialization_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEECs.png)

Comment: I assume you mean this Anaconda, see prerequisites/dependencies [link below](
https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/linux/) for package dependencies (Debian is similar to Ubuntu).

Comment: Please don't post code as images.